# Parse HTTP2 data with Python Instead Wireshark

Tags: python, okhttp, wireshark, scapy, http2

I have a PCAP file with only 1 packet , that I know it's HTTP2 protocol, so I use decode as HTTP2 and I see all the data as well ,

`HEADERS[XX]: GET /page/a/1234`

The problem is that when I look on the data with python  I see only binary data without known how to parse it to ASCII payload.

How can I parse the binary data to ASCII data of HTTP2  using Python? I couldn't file any library that done it .

Comment: Take a look at this PR: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/3374, and you can use print(l[0].show()) to look at your first and only packet.

Comment: And at scapy-ssl_tls extension for scapy with few examples: https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls

Comment: But you have to have a key or NSSKeyLog file: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Key_Log_Format